# Jquery, get elements with element name starts with a giving string

Tags: jquery, html

How using jquery get all input text elements whith a name starts with 'productElement'

Comment: Please try to google it first..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use attribute **[starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector `[name^="value"]`:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$('input[name^="productElement"]')
```